# Using Pivot to remove duplicated results adding new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following table

[_teste_calendario_Table]

[image: 1]

and when "Monstrengo" has the same value, I'd like to make a pivot, adding new columns "De1", "Ate1", "Vencimento1",
"De2", "Ate2", "Vencimento2" with the values from "De" "Ate" "Vencimento" of the duplicated rows (when I say duplicated rows, I mean rows with the same "Monstrengo" values). The expected result would be something like:

[expected_output]

[image: 2]

. I have tried to achieve this result in two different (but similar) ways. Firstly, I tried selecting [BBLA] when [BBLA] <> 1 and creating the new columns with the values of the duplicate ones. The code went something like this:

```
select *
,MAX(CASE WHEN BBLA = 2 THEN de END) AS De1
,MAX(CASE WHEN BBLA= 2 THEN Ate END) AS Ate1
,MAX(CASE WHEN BBLA= 2 THEN Vencimento END) AS Vencimento1
,MAX(CASE WHEN BBLA= 3 THEN de END) AS De2
,MAX(CASE WHEN BBLA= 3 THEN Ate END) AS Ate2
,MAX(CASE WHEN BBLA= 3 THEN Vencimento END) AS Vencimento2
from _TESTE_calendario_cliente_habilitado
GROUP BY pessoaid,BBLA,monstrengo,BBLA,DiasParaCliente,DiaInicioSemana
,De,Ate,Vencimento
```

I expected that with this the values of the duplicate rows would be translated to the new columns, and the old rows would be removed; the thing is that they weren't. I managed to add the values to the new columns, but the duplicated weren't removed and the values were added to them, not the original one.  The result when like this:

[first_Test]
[image: 3]

I thought about using pivot, but for what I have seen, I would need a single value that to pivot (only [De], for example); since I want to do it with De, Ate, Vencimento, I don't know how to use apply pivot.
Since it didn't work, I created a second table, very similar to the first, but with a second BBLA variable (BBLA_Verificador) that takes the LEAD value of BBLA (the BBLA value in the row below of the current one), so that I would be able to know if the next row was a duplicate or not. I then used the same function them before to try and get the values on the correct row. Obviously it didn't work. I managed to put the values in the first row (not the duplicates) but the values were the same as the first rows, and not the values of the duplicated ones. I also didn't menage to remove the old ones. the result was this: [_teste_calendario_Table_2]

[image: 4]

How am I supposed to do it?

Edit: To be clearer, this is an example of what my query is returning: 3 lines for the same item in Monstrengo, each line there is a separate block for De,Ate,Vencimento;De1,ate1,Vencimento1 and De2,Ate2,Vencimento2.
[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6LiB.png)
What I wish is: a single line for each Monstrengo, and if there is a second or a third set of values for De,Ate,Vencimento, that they would enter in the single Monstrengo line.
[What I wish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uLw3.png)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I like your pivot approach. The trick I think is to GROUP BY with only the column you want to be unique (Monstrengo).  This leaves out BBLA though, so you'd do a 2nd pivot for that. So, you have muliple pivots that all have the same GROUP BY to be unique like you want it, and then you join those together. Look up CTE's .. I'd be happy to help if you could say exactly what column combination you need to be unique.

Comment: @jarlh I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18.

Comment: @Josh BBLA is a simple counter for Monstrengo, it isn't important for the query. I'm looking up CTE's (thanks for the hint). I edited the post showing (hopefuly) in a clearer manner what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution; I had already tried something like it, but I problaby made a mistake with the syntax.
I changed the code

```
select *
,MAX(CASE WHEN BBLA = 2 THEN de END) AS De1
,MAX(CASE WHEN BBLA= 2 THEN Ate END) AS Ate1
,MAX(CASE WHEN BBLA= 2 THEN Vencimento END) AS Vencimento1
,MAX(CASE WHEN BBLA= 3 THEN de END) AS De2
,MAX(CASE WHEN BBLA= 3 THEN Ate END) AS Ate2
,MAX(CASE WHEN BBLA= 3 THEN Vencimento END) AS Vencimento2
from _TESTE_calendario_cliente_habilitado
GROUP BY pessoaid,BBLA,monstrengo,BBLA,DiasParaCliente,DiaInicioSemana
,De,Ate,Vencimento
```

to

```
SELECT *
,CASE WHEN LEAD(BBLA,1) OVER (PARTITION BY MONSTRENGO ORDER BY BBLA) = 2 THEN LEAD(de,1) OVER
(PARTITION BY MONSTRENGO ORDER BY BBLA) END AS De1
,CASE WHEN LEAD(BBLA,1) OVER (PARTITION BY MONSTRENGO ORDER BY BBLA)= 2 THEN LEAD(Ate,1) OVER
(PARTITION BY MONSTRENGO ORDER BY BBLA) END AS Ate1
,CASE WHEN LEAD(BBLA,1) OVER (PARTITION BY MONSTRENGO ORDER BY BBLA)= 2 THEN LEAD(Vencimento,1) OVER
(PARTITION BY MONSTRENGO ORDER BY BBLA) END AS Vencimento1
--
,CASE WHEN LEAD(BBLA,2) OVER (PARTITION BY MONSTRENGO ORDER BY BBLA)= 3 THEN LEAD(de,2) OVER
(PARTITION BY MONSTRENGO ORDER BY BBLA) END AS De2
,CASE WHEN LEAD(BBLA,2) OVER (PARTITION BY MONSTRENGO ORDER BY BBLA)= 3 THEN LEAD(Ate,2) OVER
(PARTITION BY MONSTRENGO ORDER BY BBLA) END AS Ate2
,CASE WHEN LEAD(BBLA,2) OVER (PARTITION BY MONSTRENGO ORDER BY BBLA)= 3 THEN LEAD(Vencimento,2) OVER
(PARTITION BY MONSTRENGO ORDER BY BBLA) END AS Vencimento2
FROM _TESTE_calendario_cliente_habilitado
GROUP BY _TESTE_calendario_cliente_habilitado.pessoaid, _TESTE_calendario_cliente_habilitado.Monstrengo
,_TESTE_calendario_cliente_habilitado.BBLA,_TESTE_calendario_cliente_habilitado.DiasParaCliente,
_TESTE_calendario_cliente_habilitado.DiaInicioSemana,_TESTE_calendario_cliente_habilitado.De
,_TESTE_calendario_cliente_habilitado.Ate,_TESTE_calendario_cliente_habilitado.Vencimento
```

This way I managed to get everything in the same line; I created a table with this information, and then created a view, filtering by BBLA = 1, giving me all non-duplicate rows.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).